# cl_float4 on host and float4 on device in openCL

Tags: arrays, vector, struct, kernel, opencl

So I want to define a struct thats usable on both the host and on the device in openCL that makes use of the built in openCL float4 datatypes.

On the host side, the framework comes with a cl_float4 type but on the device it's just float4.

So if I create a struct like this...

```
typedef struct
{
   cl_float4 a, b;
} MyStruct;
```

...and then try to pass that struct into a kernel (via a buffer) I get an error.

If I declare it as follows...

```
typedef struct 
{
    float4 a,b;
}
```

...that would work on the device but doesn't work on the host.

So is there a way to get it so that I can make use of openCLs built in vector types on both sides of my program within the same structs?

Answer (score 4):

The C preprocessor can help you here, by treating the code differently depending on whether it is being compiled on the host or the device.

Here's some possible solutions:

---

```
typedef struct
{
#ifdef __OPENCL_C_VERSION__
   float4
#else
   cl_float4
#endif
      a, b;
} MyStruct;
```

---

or:

```
#ifdef __OPENCL_C_VERSION__
typedef float4 cl_float4;
#endif

typedef struct
{
   cl_float4 a, b;
} MyStruct;
```

---

or:

```
#ifndef __OPENCL_C_VERSION__
typedef cl_float4 float4;
#endif

typedef struct
{
   float4 a, b;
} MyStruct;
```

---

or just use `cl_float4`, and compile the OpenCL code like this:

```
clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, "-Dcl_float4=float4", NULL, NULL);
```

---

Comment: The __OPEN_CL_C_VERSION__ macro doesn't seem to be working. My struct is declared in a .h file that I pass into the clProgram using clCreateProgramWithSource. When I include the "#ifndef __OPENCL_C_VERSION typedef cl_float4 float4 #endif", my kernel code (.cl files) produce a compiler error saying that it doesn't recognize cl_float4 which is strange because since I put in the macro it shouldn't even see that. is __OPENCL_C_VERSION__ not a universal macro? Trying the compiler flag in clBuildProgram also doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, `__OPENCL_C_VERSION__` should definitely be defined by every OpenCL compiler. Which platform/device are you using?

Comment: I'm on a macbook pro. Intel CPU, Intel HD Graphics 4000 GPU & Nvidia GeForce GT 650m GPU. Using openCL version 1.2 and I'm building on Xcode.

Comment: Have you tried doing a full clean and rebuild? Sometimes compiled OpenCL kernels get cached, and so the OpenCL code isn't recompiled when you only change the code in header files or the compiler options.

Comment: yeah I tried to clean, delete all derived data and build again. I think part of the issue is that within the ifndef I have to also add an #include <OpenCL/opencl.h> otherwise the host won't recognize the cl_float4 type. However when I try to access the float4 on the kernel side I get an error saying that the kernel can't find <OpenCl/opencl.h>. I feel like this shouldn't matter because it's within the #ifndef block.

Comment: I've just tested this on my own Macbook Pro and `__OPENCL_C_VERSION__` is definitely defined by the OpenCL compiler, and any code wrapped in `#ifndef __OPENCL_C_VERSION__` is ignored by the compiler.

Comment: Dang, not sure what to do now

Comment: So after some experimentation it does seem to be the openCL cache that was the issue. I can't seem to reliably clear it though. Every time I update the

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid this approach unless you're very careful with your struct definition. The data structure alignment rules of your OpenCL device's architecture may very well be different than those of your OpenCL host's architecture. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) for an overview on data structure alignment.

**TLDR**: the size of your struct may vary from device to host, as might the offsets from of each struct's member from the beginning of the struct. If this happens your program will break. Even if you get away with this on your current host/device combination it's not guaranteed to work on other hardware combinations.